# RStudio Global Environment shows "truncated" for large XTS-object

Tags: r, data.table, rstudio, xts

I use the latest RStudio version 1.3.959 and have a large matrix with 14,360 rows and 24,612 columns. Initially the matrix is a `data.table` object with a date-formated first column. After i convert the object to `XTS`:

```
RETURN <- as.xts.data.table(RETURN)
```

the global environment has the according entry "<truncated>". In comparison, another (much smaller XTS-object) shows the expected XTS information:

[image]

I randomly checked a couple of entries and the `data.table` to `XTS` conversion seems to be fine and no entries are lost (i guess). Due to memory limits, i am not allowed to generate a new variable and compare the initial `data.table` matrix with the converted `XTS` object.

**What exactly does "<truncated>" in the global environment pane mean and/or does this indicate that the conversion resulted in some lost data?**

Comment: It's most likely just because the information is too long since it's a lot larger, so it's not able to display the info. On latest Rstudio version, the environnement panel display the info properly, so seems like they fixed it.